# Bash variable assignment of a quoted regex

Tags: bash, shell, variables, substitution

Here's an example :

```
VALID_MODELINE_FMT=$'\'"[0-9]+x[0-9]+@[0-9]+" ([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?( [0-9]+){8} [+|-]hsync [+|-]vsync\''
REJECTED_MODELINES=$(printf "$MODELINES_STR" | grep -vE $VALID_MODELINE_FMT)
```

When running the command, I get errors that do not make any sense:

```
grep: ([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?(: No such file or directory
grep: [0-9]+){8}: No such file or directory
grep: [+|-]hsync: No such file or directory
grep: [+|-]vsync": No such file or directory
```

When substituting the variable everything works:

```
REJECTED_MODELINES=$(printf "$MODELINES_STR" | grep -vE '"[0-9]+x[0-9]+@[0-9]+" ([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?( [0-9]+){8} [+|-]hsync [+|-]vsync'
```

Basically, all I want to do is simply centralize the regex format string inside one variable because it's used at a few places.
Seems I just can't, probably because of poor substitution design inherent to shell programming.
However, I wonder if I can circumvent this, ideally without meddling with single quotes.

Thanks! :)

Comment: You need to quote format variable in `grep` command. However do check your `VALID_MODELINE_FMT` by echoing it to make sure if that is what you want.

Comment: I suggest you also post your sample input with expected output.

Comment: @Yannick: In zsh, your approach would work, but not in bash. Without quotes, bash does wildcard expansion on what you want to be your grep regexp. However, I don't see the reason for the initial `$'\'` of the regexp. The first regexp character is `"`, which does not have a particular meaning inside the regexp. There is no need for escaping it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to quote the variable *expansion*. Also, do not `printf "$var"` - use `"%s"`.

```
printf "%s" "$MODELINES_STR" | grep -vE "$VALID_MODELINE_FMT"
```

Check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net - it will get such mistakes. Prefer to use lower case variables, uppper case variables like `COLUMN` `PATH` `PWD` `USER` and many more are conceptually for exported variables.